# .htaccess redirect (rewrite) all pages to new domain main page

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to redirect (301) all pages from a no longer working e-shop to the main page of a new domain.

Can somebody tell me why this isn't working properly:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://smartshop.bg/ [L,R=301]
```

The problem is that `http://shop.topdigital.bg/index.php?p=13` goes to `smartshop.bg/?p=13`

In other words, it's copying everything after the question mark.

2 hours of research didn't solve this, so please help :(

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not adding any query string parameters of your own, the original query string is just kept – this is how it works.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/en/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule:

> *“When you want to erase an existing query string, end the substitution string with just a question mark.”*

Answer (score 0):

This should fine for you in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^ http://smartshop.bg/? [L,R=301]
```

Comment: Tried it - the same thing